# UPDATE SET information from 3 tables

Tags: mysql

table_a (item_id, item_desc)

table_b (item_id, item_name)

table_c (item_name, item_desc)

I need to `set table_a.item_desc=table_c.item_desc`

No matter what am I doing I'm still getting errors.

This is my final work:

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET table_a.item_desc = table_c.item_desc 
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
ON table_a.item_id = table_b.item_id
INNER JOIN table_c
ON table_b.item_name = table_c.item_name;
```

Comment: You're using T-SQL syntax but the `mysql` tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error. In MySQL you don't need to add `FROM` clause when using `UPDATE` with `JOIN`.
Also add table alias for better readability.

```
UPDATE table_a A
INNER JOIN table_b B ON A.item_id = B.item_id
INNER JOIN table_c C ON B.item_name = C.item_name
SET A.item_desc = C.item_desc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL the join part goes right after the `update` keyword, not to the end of the statement:

```
UPDATE table_a
  INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.item_id = table_b.item_id
  INNER JOIN table_c ON table_b.item_name = table_c.item_name 
SET table_a.item_desc = table_c.item_desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as in Update `JOIN` will be used before `SET`

```
UPDATE table_a 
      INNER JOIN  table_b ON table_a.item_id = table_b.item_id 
      INNER JOIN  table_c ON table_b.item_name = table_c.item_name
SET table_a.item_desc = table_c.item_desc;
```